# uploading .txt to FTP server adds new lines

Tags: python, ftp, newline, ftplib

I'm trying to upload a .txt file to an FTP server using Python and ftplib. Connecting works, uploading as well - just a little weird.

My file looks like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
...
```

it is created with simple writes
`file.write('line1\n)` ...

I upload it using storbinary (same with storlines)

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP() # and connecting to the server

file = open(file_name, 'rb')
ftp.storbinary('STOR file.txt', file)
```

Now, when I look at the file in the server (also tried downloading it and then looking at it), it looks like this:

```
line1

line2

line3

...
```

Why does that happen? It has to happen while uploading since until then it looks like how it's intended to.

Comment: same happens with .xml - doesn't seem to be linked to the file type

Answer (score 2):

You're creating this file under Windows and sending to a Linux FTP serwer, right?
Windows end lines with `\r\n`, and Linux with just `\n`. Using `storlines` instead of `storbinary` should fix the problem.